# Expression labeling

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling

My problem is with expression labeling in ArcMap (ArcGIS Desktop 10.5.1). I have a layer named 'Figure location'. The layer has a field- named 'Figure name' with values for instance- Fig. 1, Fig. 2, Fig. 3, Fig. 4 etc. I would like to show only the values Fig. 2 and Fig. 3 as label and not others. See the attached image.

---

[image]

Here's the image attached. Just a screen shot

Comment: You have a tag for ArcGIS Pro but your picture looks like ArcMap. Which are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a label expression to do that.

- On the *Labels* tab of the layer's properties, select *Method: Define classes of features and label each class differently*
- Click *SQL Query* and set the Where clause to `Fig_number in ('Fig. 2', 'Fig. 3', 'Fig. 4')`, → OK
- Set *Label field* to `Fig_number`

Comment: @Baky You can thank me by marking this as the answer ;-)